# EXTJS : how to insert images in a form

Tags: image, forms, extjs, extjs3

I have a problem with inserting images into a form. The addresses of the images are hosted on the database and I have to do the load dynamically through a JSON. I've ridden the JSON in PHP.
I leave a pic as have to be, and it succeeds but not dynamically.

[inserting images into a form](http://imageshack.us/a/img812/9996/picstark.jpg)

Also left the code to achieve load images into the form. It gives reference to what I have to do dynamically

```
{
fieldLabel  : 'Icono',
xtype   : 'panel',
id      : 'panelIcon',
width: 400,
height: 48,
value: 'valorIdIcon',
autoScroll:true,
layout: {
    type: 'table',
    columns: 15
    },
 defaults: {
    // applied to each contained panel
    bodyStyle:'background-color:#0099FF',
    style: 'border-color:#b5b8c8'
    },
items: 
    [{
        id: 'acces.jpg',
        width: 32,
        html: '<img src="../../Images/IconSelect/acces.jpg" onclick="javascript:verID(this);"/>',
        listeners:{
            render: function(e){ 
            e.body.on('click',function(){
            valorIdIcon = e.body.parent().parent().id;
            });
                                                    },
    }
                                            },
```

Someone give me a hand? Thanks You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished doing it from the Server-Side with PHP, wrote the code from PHP and return to front-end and did a `eval()`.

Comment: Even it works, using eval() it's a bad idea.
I suggest you to send image URLs to the client, then look through that list in Javascript and for each image create and <img> attaching an onclick event.

Comment: eval () has any security problem, but the *. jpgs are located in my server and need load any *.jpgs what are located into the folder and make the JSON appropriate.
Thanks for your suggest